# Use multiple jQuery versions in a Joomla site without renaming jQuery

Tags: plugins, joomla, jquery

I know my question is similar to many others, but I hope the specifics are different enough to justify a new question. A joomla site I'm working on uses mod_superfishmenu. This loads jQuery 1.2.6. and extends it. I'm creating a component that uses the jQuery colorbox plugin that requires jQuery 1.3 or higher and again extends JQuery. One technique to have both is reassign jQuery to another name with jQuery.noConflict(). For instance,

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js'>
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var jQuery1 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

and then change all instances of jQuery in the JavaScript code for colorbox to jQuery1, and make sure all this loads before the superfish module loads its jQuery. But I don't like having to edit the colorbox code, or remembering to edit it again if I upgrade to a newer version. So, I thought it might be possible to load the older jQuery first, then use jQuery.noConflict(true) to rename it, then load the current jQuery, and transfer the plugins attached to the first jQuery to the second one. The part that copies the plugins looks like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var oldJquery = null;
if (jQuery != undefined) {
  oldJquery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
}
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'  src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js'>
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery.noConflict();
if (oldJquery) {
  for (plugin in oldJquery.fn) {
    if (!(plugin in jQuery.fn))
      jQuery.fn[plugin] = oldJquery.fn[plugin];
  }
}
</script>
```

This seems to work, but I'm concerned that I've overlooked some detail that can bite me later on. So if anyone sees a flaw in this approach, please point it out. I also welcome any critique that shows why this is a bad idea. Thanks.

Comment: Can you not just use jQuery 1.3? This should also provide all the 1.2.6 functions.

Comment: I would really advise against loading multiple jQuery versions. Not only does this increase page load time, you're just asking for trouble.

Comment: @iHaveacomputer, it's a joomla module that loads jQuery 1.2.6. I could take jQuery 1.3 and put it in the module's javascript directory, but again I prefer not altering a standard (if out of date) module.

Comment: @Michael Mior, I can edit the code of the joomla module so it doesn't load its own jQuery, but I prefer not changing prepackaged code if I can help it. And the mod_superfishmenu module is just one example, there are any number of joomla extensions that load their own local jQuery. That's why I devised this alternative.

Comment: So you want to load perhaps 3, or 4, or 5 versions of jQuery? This doesn't sound like a better solution to me.

Comment: @Michael Mior, it's not that I want to do this. It's that sites I work on have extensions that load multiple versions, and if I modify each extension that loads a jquery not to do so, then every time a client downloads an upgraded version of the extension, I would to make the same edits again.

Comment: Correct. This would be my personal preference. When developer effort clashes with user experience, I tend to go toward user experience. (As a side note, things like these are why I'll never touch Joomla again.)

Comment: Ecellent point. I prefer WordPress over Joomla at this point, but working on Joomla's better than not working.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a simple change to mod_superfishmenu and remove the line that include jQuery 1.2.6? This way your jQuery colorbox plugin will load jQuery 1.3 itself which mod_superfishmenu will also use. Simple one line change that is not difficult to do.

As a side note I think all developers for Joomla that include any javascript library should have backend settings in order for users to enable or disabled any library should they have conflicts.

Comment: that's done commonly. Problem is, it's my component that includes jQuery 1.4. So, superfish menu would stop working when the page is displaying another component, like com_content for instance. The only framework joomla includes by default is mootools

Comment: Simple then remove the jQuery from you component and leave the one in the superfish menu. Or remove all jQuery and add it as an include in your template. Many ways to cook a fish.